# Electronics Workbench file structure

Tags: workbench

I have searched for information about the .ewb file structure, but I have come to nothing. I opened it with notepad and it´s ciphered, by no known public cipher I know. Can someone give me an advice about the file structure, or point me to another program with a known file format?

What I need is a circuit designing program for use in an app I am developing, so that i don´t have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You should probably try [Eagle](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/eagle-pcb-design-software/?language=en) or [Diptrace](http://www.diptrace.com/download.php?source=eevblog), rather than try reverse engineering something.

Comment: If you're on linux, feed the `.ewb` file into the `file` command to see if there's anything easy to get to in the contents. It may just be a common zip file with a different suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For schematic capture, [Kicad](http://www.kicad-pcb.org/display/KICAD/KiCad+EDA+Software+Suite) has a text based format which is very easy to understand and pretty well [documented](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Kicad/file_formats).

Comment: thank you, it is exactly what I was looking for.Sorry I can´t upvote it, I need 15 reputation ;)